# Cannot access odata in sap ui5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, odata, sapui5

I have my odata which is hosted from java spring boot application in backend. 
I am trying to access it from my SAP UI5 application the odata url by creating an odata model i get the following error.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("'myodataurl'/odata.svc/Users");
Error in console:

OPTIONS "myodataurl"/odata.svc/Users/$metadata 501 (Not Implemented)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "myodataurl"/odata.svc/Users/$metadata. Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'myurl' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.request.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service URL is probably just `myodataurl/odata.svc`. Please try that.
The URL `myodataurl/odata.svc/Users` is the URL to your entityset Users.

And delete the single ticks around `myodataurl`.